# How to assign escape sequences in string?

Tags: javascript

For example var myStr should have the escape sequences for backslash tab tab carriage-return new-line

```
var myStr;

myStr=("\\ \t \r \n");
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: @adeneo there is a questionmark hidden in the title :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape the escape (once!)

```
myStr = "\\\\ \\t \\r \\n";
```

when you output the string it would be "\\ \t \r \n"

Example:

```js
var myStr = "\\\\ \\t \\r \\n";

// Example output:
document.write(myStr)
```